# How can I implement a zoomable draggable interface the same as seatgeek?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, tile

Seatgeek has a zoomable draggable tiled interface.

An example is here:
http://seatgeek.com/sf-bulls-yankees-tickets/3-2-2012-tampa-george-steinbrenner-field/mlb/785875/#

I want to implement a scrollable draggable interface like this but I cannot use Google's code for google maps.
Also I need the tile system like google maps where it pulls tiles from the server for rendering the map.
Need to implement in javascript. What library can I use? How can I do it?
How does seatgeek do it?

---

I de-compiled their javascript http://pastebin.com/PVjahhnH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Map Client

  - [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org)
  - [OpenLayers Examples](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/)
- Map Data

  - [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/)

Answer (score 1):

This kind of interface seems complex to implement, but it is just some math tricks. If you decide to implement your own algorithm, try this out:

1. Take the full image and create tiles in different scales and consequently with different depth.
2. The user start looking at the scene in real scale, composed by 16 tiles created from the original scene.
   If the user drags, all tiles moves equaly. If the user zoom in, all tiles are scaled up.
3. If the user zoom more than X, you change the 16 tiles by their 16 child tiles! Got it? Higher the zoom, higher the detail. To avoid having 36000 tiles at the same time, generate with different depth and switch them on the fly.

You just need to load and move the tiles. Multiply tile x, y, width, height by the zoom. Keep the focus of the scene in the mouse position. Take a look at this [example](http://www.zoompy.net/experiment.php?id=6). It does exactly the steps above, but with a lot of microscope images. It is the same idea of google maps.

Answer (score 0):

CloudMade map tile  is one of the server based map tile service. Please read this page server http://cloudmade.com/documentation/map-tiles or contact with alex@cloudmade.com for more information.